# If $f$ is a morphism then $x\leq f(x)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> $\mathcal{A}=(A,\leq_A)$ with $\leq_A$ a well order over $A$ and $f: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{A}$ is a morphism. Then $x\leq f(x) \;\forall x \in \mathcal{A}.$

I think the proof should be obvious but I can't see it.

If $f(x)<x, f(x)=y\in\mathcal{A}$, then $y<x$ and follows $f(y)<f(x)<x$. The first inequality implies $y<f(y)$, it looks like the existence of one x such that $f(x)<x$ implies that $f(x)<x\; \forall x$, but this can't be possible because it'd imply that the image of every element would be an element "before" the element, and this can't happen for the first element of the set, this is, we can't have $f(0_{\mathcal{A}})<0_{\mathcal{A}}$.

I'm not sure if this is right...

Comment: This is not necessarily true: $x\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto x^3$ is increasing but $x^3<x$ when $0<x<1$. Can you give us more details? In particular, what are the properties or the order relation (is it total, a well-ordering)?

Comment: I think that to be able to evaluate this, a bit more information is necessary --- is $\le_A$ a partial order? preorder? Does it necessarily have a least element?

Comment: @qaphla $\leq_A$ is a well-order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This holds in a linear **well order** (the other answers show this is needed).

For suppose $L = \{x \in A: f(x) < x \}$ is non-empty.

Then this has a minimal element $m \in L$. But then $f(m) < m$ and so $f(f(m)) < f(m)$ as $f$ is a morphism. This shows that $f(m) \in L$ and $f(m) < m$ so this contradicts minimality. So $L$ is empty. Done.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you take $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$.

Comment: ... or $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$, $x\mapsto x-1$